# Javascript between Two Times

Tags: javascript, date, time

I'm currently trying to create a JavaScript which will display on our website when our shop is open, and when it is closed.

I basically want to create an if statement between two times, these being 8:30 and 5:30.

I'm currently doing the following, although it won't work as I effectively have two lots of 'minutes' defined which cancel each other out.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var Digital=new Date();
  var day=Digital.getDay();
  var hours=Digital.getHours();
  var minutes=Digital.getMinutes();

  // Monday - Open //
  if (day==1 && hours>=8 && minutes>=30 && day==1 && hours<=17 && minutes<=30)
  document.write('Open today until 5:30pm');

</script>
```

Can anyone suggest a way of achieving what I am trying to do?

Comment: @Amberlamps, my snippet above is only for demonstration. I need to show that we are open until 5:30 during opening hours, but show a message when we are closed displaying when we are next open. So for example, on Monday after 5:30, it will display 'Closed until Tuesday at 9:00'. I need to display messages based on days as we have various opening hours on various days.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
if(day == 1 && hours*60+minutes >= 510 && hours*60+minutes <= 1050) {
    // do stuff
}
```

With `8 * 60 + 30 = 510` and `17 * 60 + 30 = 1050`.

Comment: This works, but I need to be able to specify two 'days' in a second if statement. Would this work?

`// Monday - Open //
if ((day==1 && hours>=8 && minutes>=30) || (day==1 && hours<=17 && minutes<=30))
document.write('Open today until 5:30pm');

// Monday - Closed //
else if ((day==1 && hours>=17 && minutes>=31) || (day==2 && hours<=7 && minutes<=59))
document.write('Closed until Tuesday at 8:30am');`

Comment: This won´t work! When day=1, hours=20 and minutes=30, it will still write `Open today until 5:30pm`.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. Is there any way I can specify between two 'days' using your previous suggestion? (ie. Between 17:31 on a Monday and 8:29 on a Tuesday, display this message).

Comment: Sure! You can use the `day` variable with a `24 * 60 = 1440` factor.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note here is

```
new Date()
```

gets the local time from the client's clock. If the client's clock is set at a different time zone you might not get the result you are hoping for.
I would suggest getting the client's timezone as well and converting that to your desired timezone adding/subtracting any offset, start with something like

```
var clientTime = new Date();
var clientTimeZone = clientTime.getTimezoneOffset();
```

//getTimezoneOffset returns the time-zone offset in minutes between the current locale and UTC.